# Angular2: routes does not allow @:param in route param

Tags: angular, typescript

Trying to match a path at `@:param` with `/@foo`, but it keeps matching the `**` path instead, thus redirecting.

Here are my routes:

```
const routes: Routes = [
    {
        path: '',
        pathMatch: 'full',
        loadChildren: './home/home.module#HomeModule'
    },
    // ...
    {
        path: '@:username',
        loadChildren: './profile/profile.module#ProfileModule'
    },
    {
        path: '**',
        redirectTo: 'account'
    }
];

export const AppRoutesModule = RouterModule.forRoot(routes);
```

Anyone know why this is happening?

Comment: I think 'path: '@:username' should be 'path: ':id'

Comment: No, it specifically should be `@:username`. I want the @ sign in the path. If I put `:username`, the `**` would not be necessary because it would never be caught.